# Can't set state in redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-state-management

I'm trying to add 10 to the counter each time the reducer is called. I always get en error
**[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'state.loaded')]**

```
      var initialState = {
        loaded: 10
      };
      const setRandomArray = (state = initialState, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case "SETARRAY":
          return {
            ...state,
            fbArray: action.fbArray
          };
        case "CLEARARRAY":
          return {
            ...state,
            fbArray: []
          };
        case "VALUETOLOAD":
          return {
            ...state,
            counter: state.loaded + 10
          };

        default:
          return null;
      }
    };

    export default setRandomArray;
```

I am calling the reducer like this:

```
const getRandomPictures = async () => {
    store.dispatch({ type: "VALUETOLOAD" });
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think the problem is with your switch case, your reducer returns null in the **default** case which makes your state object null, try to return the state itself.